# How to protect AngularJS partials pages with Spring Security

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a Spring MVC web app and I'm using AngularJS, I want to protect my views based on roles, example if I login with and admin role I can watch the delete users partial page, and if I login with user role I can't watch the delete user partial page.

I knew how to do this with spring security but with a normal web app not with a restful Single page app with angularJS, since with angular you are not really requesting a view from the server instead you just load a partial html page in a ng-view tag.

I'm also using ngRoute to route my partials.

Here is my ngRoute.jS file

```
angular.module('MyApp')
        .config(['$routeProvider', 'USER_ROLES' ,function ($routeProvider, USER_ROLES) {
                $routeProvider.
                        when('/', {
                            templateUrl: '/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/resources/angular/templates/dashboardTemplates/dashboardTemplate.html',
                            controller: 'DashBoardCtrl',
                            access: {
                            loginRequired: true,
                            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                        }
                        }).
                        when('/login', {
                            templateUrl: '/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/resources/angular/templates/loginTemplate/login.html',
                            controller: 'LoginController', 
                            access: {
                            loginRequired: false,
                            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                        }
                        }).
                         when('/createUser', {
                        templateUrl: '/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/views/partials/userTemplates/createUser.html',
                        controller: 'UserCtrl'
                    }).
                    when('/deleteUser', {
                        templateUrl: '/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/views/partials/userTemplates/deleteUser.html',
                        controller: 'UserCtrl'
                    }).
     }]);
```

here is my spring security configuration I'm using java annotation configuration, I have adapted the configuration to convert it so it could fit a rest application

this is my Security class that extends WebSecuirtyConfigureAdapter

```
public class SegurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



public SegurityConfig() {
    super();
}
@Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/index.jsp", "/login.jsp",
                "/template/**", "/", "/error/**");
    }
//

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/failure").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").hasAnyAuthority("admin")
                .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin")
                .antMatchers("/views/partials/userTemplates/createUser.html").access("hasRole('create users')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and();
    }
}
```

I'm also using the http-auth-interceptor plugin for angularjs
here is MyApp module

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'smart-table', 'http-auth-interceptor']);
```

and here is my js file that prevents users for navigating the site without being authenticated

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $http, AuthSharedService, Session,
            USER_ROLES, $q, $timeout) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

            if (next.originalPath === "/login" && $rootScope.authenticated) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('registrese');
            } else if (next.access && next.access.loginRequired && !$rootScope.authenticated) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$broadcast("event:auth-loginRequired", {});
            } else if (next.access && !AuthSharedService.isAuthorized(next.access.authorizedRoles)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$broadcast("event:auth-forbidden", {});
            }
        });

        // Call when the the client is confirmed
        $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function (event, data) {
            console.log('login confirmed start ' + data);
            $rootScope.loadingAccount = false;
            var nextLocation = ($rootScope.requestedUrl ? $rootScope.requestedUrl : "/home");
            var delay = ($location.path() === "/loading" ? 1500 : 0);

            $timeout(function () {
                Session.create(data);
                $rootScope.account = Session;
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $location.path(nextLocation).replace();
            }, delay);

        });

        // Call when the 401 response is returned by the server
        $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function (event, data) {
            if ($rootScope.loadingAccount && data.status !== 401) {
                $rootScope.requestedUrl = $location.path()
                $location.path('/loading');
            } else {
                Session.invalidate();
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $rootScope.loadingAccount = false;
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });

        // Call when the 403 response is returned by the server
        $rootScope.$on('event:auth-forbidden', function (rejection) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
                $location.path('/error/403').replace();
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is my USER_ROLES constant js file

```
angular.module('MyApp')
        .constant('USER_ROLES', {
            all: '*',
            admin: 'admin',
            user: 'user'
        });
```

I want to protect my partials pages if I login with a user that have the normal user role I want to be able to not watch the delete or create users partial page,

I tried moving my partials outside of the resources folder and putting this in my secuirty class `.antMatchers("/views/partials/userTemplates/createUser.html").access("hasRole('create users')")` but what this does if that it blocks the partial even if I login with a user that have that role I still get the 403 error, I would like to this to happen but if I login with a user that doesn't have that role but why this happens when I login with a user that have the role is like it doesn't recognize that I have that role.

Is there a way to protect those partials based on roles like in a normal web app because that config worked in a normal web app that I worked but it looks like it doesn't work in a Single page rest app.

If it possible to protect those partials from the server side, I know that I can protect my Rest methods in the server-side using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('create users')")` but is there a way to put like an `.antMatchers("/my partials/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin")` or something similar in the security config class to protect the partials?

My folder structure

```
SpringMVCProject
--Web-Pages
  --WEB-INF
    --resources
      --angular
        --controllers
            userController.js
        --services
            userService.js
        --partials
          --userPartials
              deleteuser.html
        app.js
        permissionConstants.js
        routes.js
      --css
    --views
      --partials (I experimented putting this the folder but I 403 error)
        --userpartials
            deleteuser.html
    index.html
--Source Packages
  --controllers
    --userControllers
        UserController.java
  --secuirty
      SecuirtyConfig.java
```